How can I bypass the editing grace period? (make two revisions within 5 minutes)
I want to make an uncontroversial formatting change, then make a possibly controversial change to a post's content. The thing is, I want them to be separate revisions so that if someone rolls back the controversial change, the uncontroversial change stays (among other reasons). However, I'll have to wait 5 minutes for the grace period to expire. How can I bypass the grace period and make two separate revisions within 5 minutes?
I considered doing a rollback, but that's impractical (and there would be two unnecessary edits in the revision history - the rollback and un-rollback). There are also other cases where a rollback isn't possible, such as when I want to post a community answer copying someone else's content, then immediately edit and fix their grammar, as in this answer.
I tested if I could make the first edit then edit an old revision (similar to a rollback), but it counted under the grace period.
Reference: How does editing work?

This includes situations where the grace period ends early, but none that I can trigger as just one user. For a question, I could post an answer then delete it after doing the edit, but that seems like an abuse of the system; plus it's so involved that I'd rather just wait the 5 minutes.


I usually have the opposite problem, needing more edits without a separate revision within the grace period.

Is the reason you couldn't find a means because the post you're editing is an answer? If it's a question, as stated there, you can post a self-answer, make the edit, and then delete your answer.

It's likely the only way to post 2 separate revisions without having to wait for the 5 min grace period is to get a custom userscript. There's something similar for flagging comments without having to wait the minimum 5 seconds per flag. But I wonder why you'd want separate revisions? If you're editing why not use a single revision?

This question is, effectively: How does editing work?. That [tag:FAQ] Q&A explains how editing words and what will and won't trigger the end of the grace period. If there's a corner case that's not covered there, then that Q&A should be updated to include it, as it's expected to be complete and authoritative.

Alternately, the answer is 'You can't. See "How does editing work?" for all the things which will end the grace period, other than the ways you've already listed in this question and discarded.'

@bad Do you know how the custom userscript would work? Or could you point me to the comment-flagging one so I can study it? Thanks :) BTW I edited to add why.

@wjandrea I tried searching in https://stackapps.com but couldn't figure out which userscript it is - but I've read its functionality mentioned many times so it's there somewhere...

I understand your use case, if you're a prolific editor (I must be close to 5k edits now) sometimes a correct edit gets rolled-back for some minute reason so giving an OP 2 revisions when you're doing a substantial edit with a detail that's potentially controversial seems like a reasonable use case. (I've gotten drawn into editing arguments a lot by users who edit little or nothing, they're often wrong and won't be convinced of what a good edit entails).

"I'll have to wait 5 minutes for the grace period to expire." What is so bad about it? Your case is surely a bit unusual and typically people don't care that much about the revision history or have the need to do multiple separateedits within 5 minutes. Why not simply wait the 5 minutes and for example read something on a stackexchange or something else?

"Alternately, the answer is 'You can't. See "How does editing work?" for all the things which will end the grace period, other than the ways you've already listed in this question and discarded.'" I think this is the answer, and should, in more or fewer words, be posted as an answer here. This is a derived fact not directly within the scope of the reference Q&A. It would also be useful to include one or more references about why there is a grace period, and or why not worry about having two separate edits in the log.

(Although personally, I still think we ought to get rid of the grace period and store those separate commits. Codidact is rather deliberate about that, and having separate changes clearly labelled is good practice that I'd expect to be ingrained in Stack Exchange culture - simply because Stack Overflow came first, and that's how programmers are expected to treat version control.)

@NoDataDumpNoContribution if you check the number of weekly/mohtnly edits on large sites you'll notice that 5 minutes here and there can add up to a considerable amount of time for users who edit a lot. Knowing the OP from the editor's leaderboard this kind of feature is definitely a "power user" want. Personally I stopped editing because so many people picked arguments with me because of it.

@KarlKnechtel getting rid of the grace period is a terrible idea. I can hardly do an edit without missing several typos/details that I'll have to fix, so without the 5 minutes the revision history would be an unworkable mess (something that I don't like about GitHub btw). And no, I'm not willing to put myself under more exertion to edit flawlessly just to satisfy the demands of a revision system without a grace period - kudos to SE for getting it right.

It's still a duplicate. The FAQ post lists out the ways the grace period can be broken. Here on Meta.SE, it is policy to close questions as duplicates if they are answered in existing [tag:faq] questions, which this is. (cc @Makyen)

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog it's not a duplicate because the OP is asking for a solution so an appropriate userscript will make for an adequate answer. The question is not limited in scope to the system rules of the dup target, thus it should be reopened.

@bad_coder In that case, it should be edited to explicitly ask "Is there any user script that would allow bypassing the normal criteria for ending the grace period listed in the FAQ?"

@bad_coder I see, I didn't know that was a power user. Maybe for power users the grace period could be adjustable. Or some other more clever solution like a "merge edit with last edit if it's from me and within a reasonable time" button that is checked by default and can be unchecked for users above a certain number of successful edits.

@NoData That checkbox sounds good! I'd change the verbiage to be simpler though, like maybe "Respect grace period" with a link or hovertext that explains what it means. It could even be shown for everyone, but greyed out and off for new users and greyed out and on for users below the "certain number of successful edits". That said, yes I realize this is a pretty niche situation, so I don't see it ever being implemented.
